# struts2 upgrade - java.lang.NoSuchmethoderror

Tags: struts2

we are upgrading struts2 version from 2.0.9 to 2.3.14.2. I am getting following exception when try to print pdf file. I have googled for this error, found its related struts.xml configuration. But dont know what changes are need to do. anyone can help me with this?

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext.get(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at org.apache.struts2.views.jasperreports.JasperReportsResult.doExecute(JasperReportsResult.java:199)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:371)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:275)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)

at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)

at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)

at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:546)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:399)
at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)

at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:188)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:931)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

thanks in advance,

```
       12,143 ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar
  445,288 antlr-2.7.7.jar
    4,467 aopalliance-1.0.jar
   95,536 apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar
   51,348 appbase-0.0.jar
   26,361 asm-1.5.3.jar
   38,275 asm-commons-3.3.jar
   21,503 asm-tree-3.3.jar
  116,218 aspectjrt-1.7.0.jar
1,789,756 aspectjweaver-1.7.0.jar
   63,966 avalon-framework-4.1.3.jar
  420,860 axiom-api-1.2.13.jar
  201,829 axiom-dom-1.2.13.jar
  158,091 axiom-impl-1.2.13.jar
1,632,995 axis-1.3.jar
   33,514 axis-ant-1.3.jar
   32,062 axis-jaxrpc-1.3.jar
   19,419 axis-saaj-1.3.jar
2,302,195 axis2-1.6.2.jar
  688,884 axis2-adb-1.6.2.jar
  180,677 axis2-adb-codegen-1.6.2.jar
  107,281 axis2-clustering-1.6.2.jar
  254,405 axis2-codegen-1.6.2.jar
  147,181 axis2-corba-1.6.2.jar
   16,437 axis2-fastinfoset-1.6.2.jar
   27,749 axis2-java2wsdl-1.6.2.jar
   28,700 axis2-jaxbri-1.6.2.jar
  743,899 axis2-jaxws-1.6.2.jar
   35,742 axis2-jibx-1.6.2.jar
   19,191 axis2-json-1.6.2.jar
1,045,467 axis2-kernel-1.6.2.jar
  432,494 axis2-metadata-1.6.2.jar
   13,946 axis2-mtompolicy-1.6.2.jar
   90,445 axis2-saaj-1.6.2.jar
   33,756 axis2-soapmonitor-servlet-1.6.2.jar
   11,466 axis2-spring-1.6.2.jar
  152,926 axis2-transport-http-1.6.2.jar
   16,117 axis2-transport-local-1.6.2.jar
   27,446 axis2-xmlbeans-1.6.2.jar
  515,920 bcel-5.1.jar
1,070,477 bcprov-jdk15-133.jar
    4,136 benchmark-1.0.jar
  175,348 bsf-2.3.jar
  281,694 bsh-2.0b4.jar
  487,360 c3p0-0.9.0.jar
  193,391 carol-2.0.5.jar
  282,338 cglib-2.1_3.jar
  324,238 cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar
   37,854 classworlds-1.1.jar
   36,342 commons-attributes-api-2.1.jar
  188,671 commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
   90,001 commons-chain-1.1.jar
   41,123 commons-cli-1.2.jar
   46,725 commons-codec-1.3.jar
  575,389 commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
  100,776 commons-dbcp-1.1.jar
  143,602 commons-digester-1.8.jar
   71,442 commons-discovery-0.2.jar
  112,341 commons-el-1.0.jar
   52,543 commons-exec-1.1.jar
   68,622 commons-fileupload-1.3.jar
  279,383 commons-httpclient-3.0.jar
   87,776 commons-io-1.3.2.jar
  245,274 commons-lang-2.3.jar
  315,805 commons-lang3-3.1.jar
   60,686 commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
   44,598 commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
   39,523 commons-pool-1.1.jar
  138,956 commons-validator-1.3.1.jar
   17,978 connector-1.0.jar
   36,479 connector-api-1.5.jar
   56,404 cos-05Nov2002.jar
  281,014 cssparser-0.9.8.jar
  201,909 defaulttheme-0.0.jar
  219,244 displaytag-1.2.patch.jar
   12,799 displaytag-export-poi-1.2.patch.jar
    8,785 displaytag-portlet-1.2.jar
  313,898 dom4j-1.6.1.jar
  208,048 ehcache-1.2.3.jar
   29,557 errorhandler-0.0.jar
  291,834 FastInfoset-1.2.7.jar
  931,168 freemarker-2.3.19.jar
   34,126 geronimo-activation_1.1_spec-1.0.2.jar
   12,232 geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec-1.1.jar
  204,953 geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.6.jar
   60,214 geronimo-jaxws_2.2_spec-1.0.jar
   15,649 geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.jar
   29,445 geronimo-saaj_1.3_spec-1.0.1.jar
   28,804 geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar
   14,611 geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec-1.1.2.jar
  189,285 gson-2.2.2.jar
2,189,117 guava-14.0.1.jar
   76,643 hamcrest-core-1.1.jar
  111,504 hamcrest-library-1.1.jar
   81,271 hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final

4,495,624 hibernate-core-4.1.8.Final.jar
  102,661 hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
   79,981 howl-1.0.1-1.jar
   72,741 howl-logger-0.1.11.jar
1,230,705 htmlunit-2.11.jar
1,009,889 htmlunit-core-js-2.11.jar
  428,353 httpclient-4.2.2.jar
  223,571 httpcore-4.2.2.jar
   26,594 httpmime-4.2.2.jar
1,145,105 itext-1.3.jar
  107,344 jamon-2.4.jar
1,673,552 jasperreports-1.3.3.jar
   96,121 java-cup-11a.jar
  614,203 javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
  648,253 javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
   73,081 jaxb-api-2.0.jar
  786,408 jaxb-impl-2.0.1.jar
  854,901 jaxb-impl-2.1.7.jar
2,985,821 jaxb-xjc-2.0.1.jar
3,126,580 jaxb-xjc-2.1.7.jar
  223,395 jaxen-1.1.3.jar
   28,492 jaxrpc-api-1.1.jar
   23,618 jaxws-api-2.0.jar
  509,137 jaxws-tools-2.1.3.jar
   60,768 jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar
   11,209 jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Fina

  380,196 jcifs-1.2.19.jar
  488,686 jcommon-1.0.16.jar
    6,727 jdbc-stdext-2.0.jar
  153,253 jdom-jdom-1.0.jar
3,896,379 jdtcore-3.2.0.v_658.jar
   54,187 jettison-1.0-RC2.jar
   94,129 jetty-http-8.1.7.v20120910.jar
  103,077 jetty-io-8.1.7.v20120910.jar
  279,588 jetty-util-8.1.7.v20120910.jar
  125,273 jetty-websocket-8.1.7.v20120910.jar
1,077,819 jfreechart-1.0.1.jar
  407,900 jibx-bind-1.2.jar
  128,520 jibx-run-1.2.jar
   69,288 jmock-1.0.1.jar
  138,197 jmock-2.5.1.jar
    8,569 jmock-junit4-2.5.1.jar
   14,535 jmock-legacy-2.5.1.jar
1,008,730 jna-3.4.0.jar
    3,305 jndi-0.0.jar
  570,478 joda-time-2.1.jar
  124,316 jotm-2.0.10.jar
    5,860 jotm-jrmp-stubs-1.5.3.jar
   42,377 jotm_iiop_stubs-2.0.10.jar
    5,798 jotm_jrmp_stubs-2.0.10.jar
  813,521 js-1.6R7.jar
  358,115 jsf-api-1.1.jar
  791,660 jsf-impl-1.1_02.jar
  183,696 jsfcl-0.0.jar
   37,875 json-20080701.jar
   46,047 jsr173-1.0.jar
   49,672 jsr173_api-1.0.jar
   44,263 jsr311-api-1.0.jar
   20,682 jstl-1.1.2.jar
    8,812 jta-1.0.1B.jar
  285,638 jtds-1.2.jar
  107,364 jts-1.0.jar
   18,980 juli-6.0.16.jar
  245,039 junit-4.11.jar
  142,405 junit-dep-4.4.jar
  489,884 log4j-1.2.17.jar
  521,157 mail-1.4.7.jar
   33,243 mex-1.6.2-impl.jar
  235,867 myfaces-api-1.1.0.jar
   71,320 neethi-3.0.2.jar
  124,478 nekohtml-1.9.17.jar
1,121,434 netty-3.5.2.Final.jar
   28,569 objenesis-1.0.jar
  227,997 ognl-3.0.6.jar
    8,717 opencsv-1.8.jar
  105,026 opensaml-1.0.1.jar
  153,253 org.jdom-jdom-1.0.jar
   65,261 oro-2.0.8.jar
   46,875 pager-taglib-2.0.jar
  913,436 platform-3.4.0.jar
  219,380 plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-10.jar

  172,956 plexus-utils-1.2.jar
1,820,323 poi-3.8.jar
   38,489 poi-contrib-3.7-beta3.jar
  933,010 poi-ooxml-3.8.jar
4,706,775 poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8.jar
1,186,887 poi-scratchpad-3.8.jar
   17,090 portlet-api-1.0.jar
  101,495 provider-0.0.jar
   79,151 qdox-1.5.jar
  436,583 quartz-1.6.0.jar
   29,871 regexp-1.2.jar
  126,268 rowset-0.0.jar
   18,817 saaj-api-1.3.jar
  274,208 saaj-impl-1.3.jar
   15,808 sac-1.3.jar
  299,794 selenium-android-driver-2.28.0.jar
  140,533 selenium-api-2.28.0.jar
   10,539 selenium-chrome-driver-2.28.0.jar
2,088,917 selenium-firefox-driver-2.28.0.jar
   52,823 selenium-htmlunit-driver-2.28.0.jar
   10,466 selenium-ie-driver-2.28.0.jar
   13,461 selenium-iphone-driver-2.28.0.jar
  441,199 selenium-java-2.28.0.jar
  233,523 selenium-remote-driver-2.28.0.jar
   24,096 selenium-safari-driver-2.28.0.jar
  123,367 selenium-support-2.28.0.jar
  278,281 serializer-2.7.1.jar
  181,259 sitemesh-2.4.2.jar
   22,338 slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar
    9,678 slf4j-log4j12-1.5.6.jar
    7,583 slf4j-simple-1.5.6.jar
  307,017 smack-3.2.1.jar
  666,380 smackx-3.2.1.jar
  332,641 spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
   53,082 spring-asm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
  592,232 spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
  832,018 spring-context-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
  107,014 spring-context-support-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
  449,649 spring-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
  176,087 spring-expression-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
  404,535 spring-jdbc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
  199,112 spring-jms-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
  379,860 spring-orm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
5,643,983 spring-security-acl-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar
  788,627 spring-security-core-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar
   15,326 spring-security-ntlm-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar
   20,194 spring-security-taglibs-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar

   31,193 spring-struts-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
  117,045 spring-support-2.0.8.jar
  229,461 spring-test-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
  245,031 spring-tx-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
  548,703 spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
  577,502 spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
  200,136 sqlx-0.0.jar
  393,259 standard-1.1.2.jar
   26,514 stax-api-1.0.1.jar
  113,780 stax-utils-20040917.jar
  549,876 struts-1.2.9.jar
  329,441 struts-core-1.3.10.jar
   34,581 struts2-codebehind-plugin-2.3.14.2.jar
   45,111 struts2-config-browser-plugin-2.3.14.2.ja

  797,152 struts2-core-2.3.14.2.jar
   14,856 struts2-jasperreports-plugin-2.0.9.jar
   15,475 struts2-jfreechart-plugin-2.3.14.2.jar
   15,932 struts2-pell-multipart-plugin-2.3.14.2.ja

   23,215 struts2-plexus-plugin-2.3.14.2.jar
   43,036 struts2-sitegraph-plugin-2.3.14.2.jar
   35,898 struts2-sitemesh-plugin-2.3.14.2.jar
   21,829 struts2-spring-plugin-2.3.14.2.jar
   32,972 struts2-struts1-plugin-2.3.14.2.jar
   21,830 struts2-tiles-plugin-2.3.14.2.jar
   16,238 tiles-api-2.0.4.jar
  125,843 tiles-core-2.0.4.jar
   47,328 tiles-jsp-2.0.4.jar
  228,175 tribes-6.0.16.jar
  289,881 vecmath-1.3.1.jar
  392,124 velocity-1.5.jar
  698,567 velocity-dep-1.5.jar
  165,120 webbit-0.4.14.jar
4,063,019 webui-1.0.jar
  150,102 woden-api-1.0M9.jar
  186,268 woden-impl-commons-1.0M9.jar
   48,704 woden-impl-dom-1.0M9.jar
  148,522 wsdl4j-1.6.1.jar
  541,211 wss4j-1.5.1.jar
  504,969 wstx-asl-3.2.0.jar
3,176,148 xalan-2.7.1.jar
   91,815 xapool-1.5.0.jar
  179,491 xbean-spring-2.8.jar
1,223,877 xercesImpl-2.9.0.jar
  131,385 xfire-aegis-1.2.6.jar
  903,729 xfire-all-1.2.6.jar
   28,704 xfire-annotations-1.2.6.jar
  423,605 xfire-core-1.2.6.jar
   64,061 xfire-generator-1.2.6.jar
   25,055 xfire-java5-1.2.6.jar
   20,278 xfire-jaxb2-1.2.6.jar
   43,912 xfire-jaxws-1.2.6.jar
    8,074 xfire-jsr181-api-1.0-M1.jar
   55,761 xfire-spring-1.2.6.jar
   14,588 xfire-ws-security-1.2.6.jar
   11,936 xfire-xmlbeans-1.2.6.jar
  194,354 xml-apis-1.3.04.jar
   84,091 xml-resolver-1.2.jar
2,722,970 xmlbeans-2.5.0.jar
  124,724 xmlParserAPIs-2.6.2.jar
  127,961 XmlSchema-1.1.jar
  148,829 XmlSchema-1.4.7.jar
  284,773 xmlsec-1.3.0.jar
   24,677 xpp3_min-1.1.3.4.O.jar
  545,752 xstream-1.2.jar
  637,221 xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar
```

Comment: It's almost certainly a dependency mismatch. You must use the dependencies specified by the library versions in question. Consider using a tool like Maven to manage your transitive dependencies.

Comment: we are using for maven for dependencies...I have found one link with similar issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3754?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel. i have followed the instructions mentioned but still no luck... :(

Comment: I would be *very* surprised if it's not a dependency mismatch. Did you to a `mvn clean` before rebuilding? Can you post your existing deployed libraries?

Comment: yes, i did mvn clean and manually deleting application and work folder in tomcat. I dont know how to post deployed libraries list. I see a list of 294 libraries in Web-Inf/lib folder. But i have removed xwork-2.1.3 and old ognl library. still not working. are there any particular libraries that cause these type of issues?

Comment: It'd be the xwork library. I don't see how you'd have 300 libraries in your app. You post a list of libraries by doing a directory and cutting and pasting the text.

Comment: i have edited question and added the list of libraries...please look at it once.

Comment: @siva Are you seriously thinking that providing 300+ libraries you could resolve the issue by picking each one and removing it then restarting the server to check for errors? Or you have googled the net to find a tool that do library optimizations?

Comment: dont know how to solve this... :( basically what we doing is upgrading struts2 version from 2.0.9 to 2.3.14.2 and i have upgraded corresponding libraries also..dont know which one causing the issue.this is the list struts2-codebehind-plugin, struts2-config-browser-plugin, struts2-jfreechart-plugin
struts2-junit-plugin, struts2-pell-mulitpart-plugin, struts2-plexus-plugin, struts2-sitegraph-plugin
struts2-sitemesh-plugin, struts2-spring-plugin, struts2-struts1-plugin, struts2-tiles-plugin 
didnt upgrade jasperreports and struts2-jasperreports-plugin as need to re-write reports

Comment: Are you actually *using* all the S2 plugins you list?! And why are you deploying selenium libs? In any case, obviously it's the ancient version of the Jasper plugin. You can *want* it to work all you want, but it won't, upcoming release or not. There are several other duplicate libs in there you should keep an eye on.

Comment: Also post your pom.xml.

Comment: We solved it. Even with the version mis-match, we have some module which do the things in similar manner. So we used that code as a round-about solution. In next release we will work on upgrading struts2-jasper plugin too. thank you all for your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

OMG. 
I've already seen a lot of dependency in a project, but you beat them all. Note this is *NOT* a good thing.

BTW, a quick look at the stacktrace and to the dependencies list shows that you are using `struts2-jasperreports-plugin-2.0.9.jar`. To be consistent with others struts 2 libraries, you should upgrade to `struts2-jasperreports-plugin-2.3.14.2.jar`.

Comment: we have some jasper reports which are working fine, except this one place. I have tried that upgrading struts2-jasper plugin too, but when we upgrade that, jasperreports are not at all working. And we dont have time to re-wirte them as it has release soon.

Comment: S2 plugin versions need to match the version you are using though, you can't upgrade the framework and not the plugins. Your release timeline is irrelevant to this. Why not put off the upgrade of S2 to a later date then?

Comment: You can't upgrade a library (here S2) without having a look to the required versions of the needed dependencies (jasperreports). You either have to revert the S2 version update or try upgrade jasperreports. Which, in turn, can leads you to upgrade another dependency, and so on...

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the struts 2 'required' tag attribute has been replaced by 'requiredLabel'.  You need to search for things like required="true" or required="false" in your JSP struts 2 tags, and replace by requiredLabel="true" or requiredLabel="false"

Answer (score 0):

we were also facing this problem.
But in our case we are not using jasper and json.

while upgrading struts we were just replacing new jar files, but this is not enough.

we need to recompile the java files(The modules which uses strus and xwork APIs) with new struts jars.

After that the issue is resolved.